# Get all empty location in collection using geometry node

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have multiple 'empty' instances of a cube with a geometry node. The nodes increase the z-scale of each instances along the y-axis. However, the instances only reference the location of the original cube instead of each individual empty. i tried the collection info node but it dont have 'location' output.
The right side demonstrates how I want it to be, and I prefer to use 'empty' for instancing if possible.thanks.[image]

Comment: tbh...you ask about a technical solution. But i think it would make more sense to explain in detail what kind of animation/picture you want to achieve. There might be much better ways to do that...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You're right, there is a better way to achieve it. I was just trying to figure out how instancing location works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create some empties, select them, <kbd>M</kbd> add to a new collection *"Empties"*, then create a cube (you of course deleted the default cube?), and add geonodes modifier to it:

[image]

Now moving the empties along $y$ axis will scale the cube (make sure the bottom of the cube is on the $z = 0$ plane so it scales only up):

[image]

Comment: Your instructions were spot-on. Thanks!